# Do layout anchors appear in Interface Builder?

Tags: autolayout, interface-builder

In Interface Builder, I can only see a view's "margin" mentioned.

Yet, in code, one can use layout anchors and also, a view has a "layoutMarginsGuide".

Why do anchors only appear in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layout anchors are not actual participants in auto layout, they are only convenience entities that exists to provide a nicer way to programmatically create constraints. From the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutAnchor_ClassReference/):

> The NSLayoutAnchor class is a factory class for creating
>   NSLayoutConstraint objects using a fluent API

Since Interface Builder already provides its own convenience mechanisms for generating constraints, there is no need for it to use the layout anchor metaphor. Keep in mind that the outputs from layout anchors are the same constraints that are created using other mechanisms (including Interface Builder), so it's best to consider the layout margins guide and layout anchors as **how**s and not **what**s. Interface Builder is itself different **how** to achieve the same **what** as anchors.